# Display set of items in array(list of type X)

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I display a specific set of items in an array?

I want to print 25 items to screen from index 0 to 24 and another 25 starting from index 25, in that order.

I can display all items, but how can I display from a specific index in the array to another specific index?

Example: I have 100 items in my array.

And I want to show from 0 to 3 and from 4 to 7 and so on.

For Example: String of letters: A B C D E F G etc.
And I want to show only A B C. But when I do something it show next 3 in array.

Since im using B_items as object in an array. I wanna show only 0, 1, 2 in array and again form 3, 4, 5 and so on.

```
public class B_items
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value { Get; set;}
}


B_items[,] items;
 public Inventory(Backpack Bpack, int Columns, int Rows, int SlotWidth, int SlothHeight, Vector2 Pos)
    {
        items = new B_items[Columns, Rows];
        pos = Pos;
        slotWight = SlotWidth;
        slotHeight = SlothHeight;
        backpack = Bpack;
        this.Columns = Columns;
        this.Rows = Rows;

        LoadItems(Bpack);
    }

for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WritleLine(Items[i].Name;
}
   }
                if (items[X, Y] != null)
                {

                    spriteBatch.Draw(items[X, Y].Texure, new Rectangle(DrawX, DrawY, slotWight, slotHeight),new Rectangle(0,0,64,64),Color.White);
                    if (items[X, Y].StackSize > 1)
                    {
                        spriteBatch.DrawString(AssetManager.GetInstance().font["Arial8"], items[X, Y].StackSize.ToString(), new Vector2(DrawX + 24, DrawY + 22), Color.White);
                    }

                }
```

This will write all and I want to do 5 of those. While I have 100 and each time I press a button it shows next 5 in that list.

How can I show specific list of items...form index 0 to 10 and form 11 to 20 and so on.

```
var stats = items.Skip(5).Take(5)
```

I can't do this... I do not see `.Take(param)` or `.Skip(param)`

I am using

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
```

*I'm sorry for not being specific. I can't nor sometimes know how to ask a valid question. My English is not my first language so fix my grammar and delete this line*

Comment: Show us some sample data or expected output.

Comment: Try a `for`-loop, maybe combined with `if (...)` and some simple calculations, or two nested `for`-loops.

Comment: it depends on your array, if it is one dimension, a for loop and a range can fulfill your need. FOR EXAMPLE "for (int x =0; x< 3; x++) { string y = a[x];  }", so each of y is your wanted item from the range 0 to 3

Comment: Your code does not compile. Check `B_items`and `B_item`and `Items` and `items`.

Comment: @sefe that was just example. I was no looking to be correct to letter;

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to access ranges of your array. `Skip` lets you decide where you start your range and `Take` how many entries you want.

If you want `D E F` from your example you can use:

```
var subRange = items.Skip(3).Take(3);

foreach (string item in subRange) {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Where do you find range?

Comment: @LikodricVladan: This is an example. You replace it with your array. If you don't provide source code, you'll get examples in the answer that you have to adapt.

Comment: Use `Items`(or `items`) instead of range.

Comment: Tried 
    var SubRange = items. (take or skip not exist)

Comment: You have to include the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: Have you referenced the System.Core assembly? And are you using a multi-dimensional array or not? Your code is ambiguous. Please make sure it compiles, so that it becomes clear.

Comment: multi-dimensional array  it is. And`using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;`

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to show from 0 to 3 and from 4 to 7 and so on.

You can use a normal for-loop and specify the step size that you want to increment. Every step you would skip the items that you have already processed and take each time only the specified step size (in your case 3). 
This should do the trick:

```
// test array 
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();

int stepsize = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += stepsize)
{
    string s = String.Join(" ", array.Skip(i).Take(stepsize));
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```